# Reformatting HTML of list that comes from a dynamic hash

Tags: html, css, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller

I have a rails application that scrapes and lists information from a URL entered into a search bar. The lists are always different. I'm trying to format these dynamic lists. **I want to insert a break between each item and bullet each item in an unordered list.**

I'm not the best with HTML or CSS and I can't quite figure out how to reformat the HTML list. It works fine as far as the controller and the listing. There's also a second version above with buttons for saving if the user is signed in, but the code is longer and I can probably figure that out as it's very similar to this part.

@sources is a hash with descriptions and their associated links

This is the bottom half of my sources-container (it lists sources from Wikipedia pages)

```
<% else %>
<div class="container-fluid col-md-10" style="background-color:#eaf3ff"> 
<br><h2><strong><%= @page.title %></strong></h2><hr>
<h5> Summary </h5>
<p> <%= @page.summary %> </p> <hr> <br>
<% @sources.each do |description, link| %>
<div class="col-lg-16">
<span>  <%= link_to description, link, target: :_blank %> </span> 
<% end %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

It works but the formatting is off. I can't figure out how to format it without breaking the HTML. I'm thinking there's some way to do this in CSS but I'm very inexperienced with CSS.

All I'm doing from the index is this:
<%= render 'layouts/sources-container' %>

Answer (score 1):

`<div class="col-lg-16">` is missing a closing tag.

Put `ul` tag outside of `.each do` block to render it once. `li` tag goes inside `.each do` block and gets rendered multiple times, so you end up with:

```
<ul>
  <li> <a></a> </li>
  <li> <a></a> </li>
  ...
</ul>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul

```
<ul>
  <% @sources.each do |description, link| %>
    <li>
      <%= link_to description, link, target: :_blank %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Check bootstrap for available css classes (i'll guess it's v4)

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/list-group/